# Cannot search in application menu launcher

Tags: slingshot

I cannot search in application menu launcher (hmm, i think it's slingshot). I can open the menu and launch the applications from menu. But, I really cannot search in the app-menu-launcher. I don't know what was wrong.

Thank you.

[image: app-menu-launcher]

Comment: I have same problem please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that this is caused by `ibus-daemon` program. If you have ibus running on startup, remove it or add a startup item to kill the `ibus-daemon`. You should be able to search in Slingshot launcher.

Comment: it solved perfect. really appreciated. kudos!

Comment: Please include instructions for *how* to do this for less experienced users.

Comment: @RolandiXor adding a command `killall ibus-daemon` will do the job

Answer (score 1):

After having temporarily solved following your suggestion, that is stopping the ibus-daemon service, I have tried to reset it's configuration (`ibus -reset-config`), and now the problem is disappeared, also after having rebooted, with the ibus daemon active.

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem. Different cause.

**Problem:**
The search in "Applications" can be disabled when installing Windows programs via Wine. A 120 character directory was generated including spaces during the install that disabled the search function. It was traced to this directory
~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs$

Not good.

**Solution:**
Removed program,*.desktop files, and dead directory name w/spaces. Applications search feature works as designed. Maybe a function tree search code change in Applications can fix this problem. If I can break it, I guarentee someone else will too.

**Lesson:**
For Wine,known Gold/Platinum programs only. If need to use a windows program. Use Windows.

**Note:**
If your Windows programs run in wine, make sure you check in the wine programs files and ensure the directory names do not contain spaces. Remove them if you want to search Applications.