# Can't input anything into app menu search box

Tags: slingshot

The problem is that I can't type anythin into text box. Also Backspace and delete buttons don't work.

[image]

Meanwhile, I can use context menu, so we can make sure that the search itself is working succesfully.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this bug (it bogs me too). 
loki 0.4 is running on an Intel-based  PC using Kernel 4.4.0-36-generic

When I investigated into it I found that different users have different behaviour (typing is possible for another user). 
I created a new user by

```
sudo useradd -c 'elementary test user 0' -d /home/elementary0 -m -s /bin/bash  elementary0
```

added a password.

When switching to that user the input/search works.

So it might be that some "old user settings" causing this behaviour.

Could someone help, which settings causing this behaviour?

Comment: It happens when ibus runs.

Comment: @anwar, can you elaborate please? What kind of processes causes ibus to run? how do I turn it off?

Comment: @yeedle I've written [an answer](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7776/cannot-search-in-application-menu-launcher/9527#9527) to a similar question. The process is `ibus-daemon`. Killing it enabled me to input